# Java(BlueJ) Adding up all numbers between two integers

Tags: java, integer

I'm creating a method to add up all numbers between two integers.
I currently have:

```
/**
 * Add up all numbers between two integers
 */
public void Sum(int a,int b)
{
   int result = 0;
    while (a <=b) 
    {
        result+=a;
        a++; 
    }   

    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is "+result); 
}
```

This only works if `a <= b`. How do i also do it for if `a > b` ?

I have to use a while loop

Comment: "How do i also do it for if a > b ?" => Switch them!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your questions will be a *lot* easier to read if you take the time to format the code appropriately, with clear indentation.

Comment: What i meant was, so it takes into account a > b as well as the already created rule for a <=b

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to reuse what you already have. Let's rename your method first:

```
public void sumMonotonic(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (a <=b) {
       result+=a;
       a++; 
    }       
    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is "+result); 
}
```

So `sumMonotonic()` only works if its first argument is no bigger than its second. But now we can define `sum()` like this:

```
public void sum(int a, int b)
{
    if (a<=b)
        sumMonotonic(a,b);
    else
        sumMonotonic(b,a);
}
```

This just invokes the other function with the arguments in the appropriate order.

Actually there's one other oddity that we might fix. It seems a little unidiomatic to have a `sumMonotonic()` method that does the printing. It would be better if it returned the sum, and if the `sum()` method did the printing. So we'd refactor it like this:

```
public int sumMonotonic(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (a <=b) {
       result+=a;
       a++; 
    }
    return result;
}

public void sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result;
    if (a<=b)
        result = sumMonotonic(a,b);
    else
        result = sumMonotonic(b,a);
    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is "+result); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Sum(int a,int b)
 {
       int result = 0;
       if(a>b) //swap them
       {
          result=a;
          a=b;
          b=result;
          result=0;
       }
        while (a <=b) {
        result+=a;
        a++; 
  }   

   System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is "+result); 
   }
```

Comment: I guess it would make more sense if the arguments are switched (`Sum(a, b)` and `Sum(b, a)`). The `Sum` method itself shouldn't care about that.

Comment: yah that efficient one i admit, if the calling context `Sum(int a,int b)` was visible in the question . @Tom